# Python PyTelegramBotApi при прохождении цикла for бот не ожидает ответа, а просто выполняет дальше и никакие register_next_step_handler не работают

Tags: python, telebot

```
@my_bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'], commands=['start_v'], func=lambda message: True)
def start_v(message):
    guestions=open_task('guestions')
    @my_bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def register_result(message, name_task):
        guestions=open_task('guestions')
        mess=message.text
        if dict(guestions[name_task])['result']==mess:gres.append(mess);print('g')
        else:bres.append(mess);print('b')
    my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Запуск викторины "{}"\nОтвет поменять нельзя\nПосле запуска каждое сообщение регистрируется как ответ на вопрос\nВыбор ответа будет происходить пока вы не отправите\выберите ответ!.'.format(open_task('name')))
    bres=[]
    gres=[]
    var=1
    for name_task in guestions.keys():
        if guestions.get(name_task)['type']=='1':
            value=guestions.get(name_task)['vars']
            keyboard=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True,True)
            key1=types.KeyboardButton(text=value[0])
            key2=types.KeyboardButton(text=value[1])
            key3=types.KeyboardButton(text=value[2])
            key4=types.KeyboardButton(text=value[3])
            keyboard.add(key1, key2)
            keyboard.add(key3, key4)
            my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вопрос №{}:\n\t{}".format(var,name_task), reply_markup=keyboard)
            my_bot.register_next_step_handler(message, register_result, name_task)
            time. Sleep(2)
            my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ засчитан")
            var+=1

    my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Викторина завершена")
    my_bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Результаты: \nПравильные ответы: {len(gres)}\nНеправильные ответы: {len(bres)}")
```

Так же у меня возникает ошибка telebot что функции register_result нужен еще один аргумент name_task

open_task() возвращает словарь но с этим я уже разобрался, если это поможет то вот как выглядит словарь:

```
{'Вопрос 1': {'type': '1', 'vars': ['Ответ', 'Ответ', 'Ответ', 'Ответ'], 'result': 'Ответ'}, 'Вопрос 2': {'type': '1', 'vars': ['Ответ', 'Ответ', 'Ответ', 'Ответ'], 'result': 'Ответ'}, 'Вопрос 3': 
{'type': '1', 'vars': ['Ответ', 'Ответ, 'Ответ', 'Ответ'], 'result': 
'Ответ'}}
```

Comment: Потому что это так не работает

Comment: А как это должно работать? Просто я впервые с данной библиотекой, и ответа нигде не видел, документацию читал

Comment: На каждый свой вопрос вам стоит сделать отдельный хендлер, а не циклом извращаться

Comment: просто мне нужно чтобы вопросы можно было изменять не меняя код, а меняя файл txt который преобразует open_task()